# Prove that there are infinite integers that satisfy $a^2 + b^2 + 2017 = 2019ab.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

How do you prove that there are infinite pairs of integers (a,b) that satisfy
$a^2 + b^2 + 2017 = 2019ab$?

Comment: In what context did you encounter this question?

Comment: Counterexample $(a,b) = (1,2)$, because $1^2 + 2^2 + 2017 = 2022$ but $2019 \times 1 \times 2 = 4038$ or is there something I don't get?

Comment: @HenriMenke the question doesn't ask to show that it holds for **any** two integers- just that there are  infinitely many integer pairs that satisfy this relation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any positive integer $\mu$, let $\rho = \mu + 2$ and $\displaystyle\;\lambda = \frac{\rho + \sqrt{\rho^2-4}}{2}$, we have 
$$\lambda^{-1} = \frac{\rho - \sqrt{\rho^2-4}}{2}\quad\implies\quad \lambda + \lambda^{-1} = \rho$$

Consider following $4$ sequences for $n \ge 0$.

$$\begin{cases}
T_n &= \lambda^n + \lambda^{-n}\\
U_n &= \frac{\lambda^n - \lambda^{-n}}{\lambda-\lambda^{-1}} = \frac{\lambda^{n} - \lambda^{-n}}{\sqrt{\rho^2-4}}\\
A_n &= \frac12(T_n + \mu U_n)\\
B_n &= \frac12(T_n - \mu U_n)
\end{cases}$$
It is easy to see all of them satisfy a recurrence relation of the form

$$f_{n+2} - \rho f_{n+1} - f_n = 0$$

Notice $$(T_0,T_1) = (2,\rho), (U_0,U_1) = (0,1)\quad\implies\quad
(A_0,A_1) = (1,\rho-1), (B_0,B_1) = (1,1)$$
are all integers. By induction, all $T_n, U_n, A_n, B_n$ are integers.

Notice
$$\begin{align} & A_n^2 + B_n^2 - \rho A_n B_n\\
= & \frac14\left((T_n + \mu U_n)^2 + (T_n - \mu U_n)^2 - \rho((T_n + \mu U_n)(T_n - \mu U_n)\right)\\
= & \frac14\left((\rho+2)\mu^2 U_n^2 - (\rho-2) T_n^2\right)\\
= & \frac{\mu}{4}\left((\rho^2-4)U_n^2 - T_n^2\right)\\
= & \frac{\mu}{4}\left((\lambda^n - \lambda^{-n})^2 - (\lambda^n + \lambda^{-n})^2
\right)\\
= & -\mu\end{align}
$$

We find $(a,b) = (A_n,B_n)$ are solutions to the equation

$$a^2 + b^2 + \mu = (\mu + 2)a b\tag{*1}$$

It is easy to see $\lambda > 1$. This implies $A_n,B_n$ are unbounded.
As a result, equation $(*1)$ has infinitely many integer solutions.

The question at hand is a special case of this with $\mu = 2017$.

**Update**

It turns out there is a simpler way to generate infinitely many solutions to an equation of the form:

$$a^2 + b^2 + \mu = (\mu + 2) a b\quad\text{ where }\quad \mu \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}\tag{*2}$$

First, $(a,b) = (1,1)$ is a solution.

Second, treat $a$ as a parameter, the problem becomes finding the root of a quadratic polynomial in $b$. By
[Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas),
if $b$ is a root, so does $(\mu + 2)a - b$. This means whenever
$(a,b)$ is a solution, so does $((\mu+2) a - b, a)$.

Construct sequence
$\displaystyle\;b_n = \begin{cases}
1, & n = 0, 1\\
(\mu+2)b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}, & n \ge 2
\end{cases}$,
all $(b_{n+1},b_n)$ will be solutions to $(*2)$.

Notice $b_2 = \mu+1 > b_1 > 0$. Furthermore, if $b_n > b_{n-1} > 0$,  then
$$b_{n+1} - b_n = \mu b_n + (b_n - b_{n-1}) > \mu b_n > 0$$

This implies $b_{n+1}$ is strictly increasing. As a result, all those solutions of the form $(b_{n+1},b_n)$ are distinct and $(*2)$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: How did you apply Vieta's formula to get $(μ+2)a−b$ from b?

Comment: @joeken You have a quadratic polynomial $x^2 - Ax + B = 0$ with $A = (\mu+2)a$ and $B = a^2 + \mu$. If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the two roots, then $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = A \implies \lambda_2 = A - \lambda_1$. So if $\lambda_1 = b$, then $\lambda_2 = (\mu + 2)a - b$.

Comment: One last question, when you say, "if $b_n > b_{n-1}$", how do you know that it's true?

Comment: @joeken First, $b_n > b_{n-1}$ is true at $n = 2$ by brute force. The next part   "if $b_n > b_{n-1}, \ldots$ is just standard way of carrying out induction. The chain of deduction is essentially $$b_2 > b_1 \implies b_3 > b_2 \implies b_4 > b_3 \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$a^2+b^2+2017=2019ab \iff (a-b)^2=2017(ab-1)$

Answer (score 0):

$a^2 + b^2 + 2017 = 2019ab \implies (2 a - 2019 b)^2 - 2017\cdot 2021 b^2 = -4\cdot 2017$

It is Pell equation with infinite set solutions.

First some solutions:

```
(a, b) = (2018, 1)
(a, b) = (4074341, 2018)
(a, b) = (8226092461, 4074341)
(a, b) = (16608476604418, 8226092461)
(a, b) = (33532506038227481, 16608476604418)
(a, b) = (67702113082704679721, 33532506038227481)
(a, b) = (136690532781474710129218, 67702113082704679721)
(a, b) = (275978117983684357046211421, 136690532781474710129218)
(a, b) = (557199683518525935401590729781, 275978117983684357046211421)
(a, b) = (1124985885045785879891454637216418, 557199683518525935401590729781)
(a, b) = (2271345944707758172974911510949218161, 1124985885045785879891454637216418)
...
```